# Git-merge error

Tags: github, git-merge, git-commit, git-stash

I am trying to practice contributing to other repositories on Github but I am getting an errors while I try merging 2 branches:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        game.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

and here is the git status output:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   game.js
```

I tried git push as well but

```
$ git push
remote: Permission to udacity/asteroids.git denied to Oalbacha.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/udacity/asteroids.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Can you please help? Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you!

Comment: And if you see in your status, it still says you have uncommitted changes made to the file game.js. If you have modified the file again, you need to commit/reset those changes before trying to merge.

Comment: The push is resulting in the error code 403 because you are not allowed to push to the branch of that project. The project masters have to grant you permission for you to be able to push to it's master. Try doing the same with another branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to have solved my problem

```
Omar F Albacha (master +) asteroids $ git branch -d coins
warning: deleting branch 'coins' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/coins', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch coins (was 354dfdd).
Omar F Albacha (master +) asteroids $ git branch --no-merged
  easy-mode
Omar F Albacha (master +) asteroids $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   game.js

Omar F Albacha (master +) asteroids $ git commit
[master 2449dd1] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Omar F Albacha (master) asteroids $ git merge master coins
merge: coins - not something we can merge

Did you mean this?
        origin/coins
Omar F Albacha (master) asteroids $ git checkout coins
Switched to a new branch 'coins'
Branch coins set up to track remote branch coins from origin.
Omar F Albacha (coins) asteroids $ git branch
* coins
  easy-mode
  master
Omar F Albacha (coins) asteroids $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Omar F Albacha (master) asteroids $ git branch
  coins
  easy-mode
* master
Omar F Albacha (master) asteroids $ git merge master coins
Auto-merging game.js
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 game.js | 161 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------
 1 file changed, 115 insertions(+), 46 deletions(-)
```

There was a guide on stack overflow about cleaning out outdated branches.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have modified the file and you have not committed it before merging.

Run `git commit` first and then merge it, or if you don't want those changes to be included in the merge, do `git reset` and then try merging.

Another option is to stash the changes somewhere before merging so that you can go and check them later.

Comment: I have committed and added a message. I have also tried stashing but I am still getting this error though. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong :(